# Testing: mocking multiple status code responses

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am testing my http responses.

I would like to write a test that says any status between 200 and 300 is valid and anything else is invalid.

However to test a status code, I must first create a mock response like so:

```
before(() => {
   mockResponse = new window.Response(JSON.stringify(mockResponseData), {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
   fetchMock.post('/myurl',mockResponse)
})

it('Should ...')
```

Notice that I set the status directly. Therefore when creating a mock test I have to set a status. How can I test a range of statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that to test each cases :

```
describe('http tests', function () {

  var codes = [];
  for(var code = 200; code < 300; code++){
    codes.push(code);
  }

  codes.forEach(function(code){
    it(`should responds with a ${code} status`, function () {

      mockResponse = new window.Response(JSON.stringify(mockResponseData), {
         status: code,
         headers: {
           'Content-type': 'application/json'
         }
       })
      fetchMock.post('/myurl',mockResponse)

      //test code
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Was hoping not to have to do that but I guess that's the only solution.

Comment: You could also use a lib like chance or a simple random to generate a number between 200 and 300. But it will not be reproducible :/